# Are they the same thing in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> In a paper published on May 26th in npj Climate and Atmospheric
> Science, Nikolaos Christidis, a climatologist at the Hadley Centre, a
> branch of the British Met Office, look at what might be ***in store*** for
> the Mediterranean and the Middle East ***in a future***, even hotter world.

"in store" in cambridge dictionary has the meaning of "going to happen soon". Is it the same meaning of "in a future"? Either of them is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

**In a future** is not an established phrase; the sentence refers to **a future world** that will be even hotter than the world is at present.

Answer (score 0):

No. The prepositional phrase “in a future, even hotter world” means, essentially, “given that the world is going to continue to heat up.” So that phrase is describing the context for understanding why “what might be in store” might indeed be in store.